# Strings, Unions, and Pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, unions

Note: This is an assignment. I'm looking for solutions using unions, because it's part of the assignment. I provide the solution I want to use, but I need help putting this concept and approach into perspective. ---

I'm aware of how strings don't work in unions, and this question has been asked before - but they all seem to end suggesting Boost. I saw someone, however, suggest pointers but it appeared overlooked and I wanted more clarification on it. Below I have two structs, with a union containing pointers to both structs as a workaround:

```
struct HourlyInfo {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string title;
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
};

struct SalaryInfo {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string title;
    double salary;
    double bonus;
};

union Employee {
    HourlyInfo *hourlyEmployee;
    SalaryInfo *salaryEmployee;
};
```

**Is there anything wrong with this method?** To me it seems to defeat the purpose of a union.

EDIT: This is an assignment, but it's very open-ended. I'm not looking for answers, just explanations and input on why a certain method might or should be avoided. My alternative is using `cstring`, but I'm trying to weigh the pointer method (in order to have the convenience of `string`) against just using `cstring`.

EDIT #2: I understand that unions will make one struct void once the other is defined. I will be creating an array of these unions, and the use of union for this case is warranted because any employee is EITHER hourly or salary. My concern is the use of strings and pointers as a workaround.

Comment: You need to me more specific about what you're asking. This question could be downvoted otherwise.

Comment: You've tagged this question as a C++ question. Is there a reason you're not using classes instead of a union?

Comment: It should work. But why don't you use inheritance instead of unions?

Comment: Is the assignment specifically asking you to use unions? Or are you trying to use unions to solve a specific request of your assignment?

Comment: @Arrieta yes, it is. Please see my edits.

Comment: If you code in C++ - use `string` instead of `cstring`.

Comment: @sunday I don't see in your edits how is your assignment asking you to use unions. Unless the assignment is itself "is this code correct?"

Comment: Thanks to c++11s generalized unions, you can use strings: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also possibly use anonymous unions and structs:

```
struct Employee {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string title;
    bool isHourly;
    union {
        struct {
            double hourlyRate;
            int hoursWorked;
        } hourly;
        struct {
            double salary;
            double bonus;
        } salaried;
    };
};
```

Then access them via `Employee emp; emp.hourly.hourlyRate = 100;`
You may even remove struct names - then you shall be able to access their fields as `emp.salary`.
Your approach is fine still - assuming you have where to store info to check if the worker is salaried or hourly. The other pointer won't be null, it will be the same pointer to the same data - but treated like another type, so it may lead to undefined behavior.

I myself would still prefer something like strategy pattern though.

Comment: My professor asked us specifically to create a union containing the two relevant structures, but I think he really just wanted us to use unions ('how' was up to us). This is simple and still demonstrates an understanding of unions, so it WFM. I'll argue my case if he has a problem with it :-)

Comment: Since the primary purpose of unions (I believe) is to save memory, would your solution be more memory efficient than my pointer implementation?

Comment: @sunday it should be approximately the same, if you have added bool, as the approximate difference is size of pointer on your side vs size of double minus size of int on my side which is 0 if int and pointer are 4 bytes. The actual thing are usually more complex since compiler may, for instance, reserve some extra memory when using new to save count of bytes allocated, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way of doing this is with inheritance.

```
struct EmployeeInfo {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string title;
};

struct HourlyInfo : public EmployeeInfo {
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
};

struct SalaryInfo : public EmployeeInfo {
    double salary;
    double bonus;
};
```

Give it a virtual destructor so that you can delete by base class pointer. And store a pointer to `EmployeeInfo` instead of the union. Upcast as necessary. And account for the difference via virtual functions, or an "Employee type" variable somewhere. In the union scenario, you'll need it anyway, as the union itself doesn't tell you which data item in it is the relevant one.

Yes, you can derive `struct`'s. And you can have member functions in them, too.

Comment: but it's gonna be pain to distinguish between a HourlyInfo and SalaryInfo in an array of pointers to EmployeeInfo

Comment: This doesn't quite follow the requirements of my assignment or answer my question; or at the very least I'm not understanding where unions come into play here. Feel free to counter that though (that was the purpose of my asking).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't see they were pointers, yes that is completely pointless. Also you'll get a crash when allocating a HourlyInfo and accessing the SalaryInfo::bonus member. Since one struct is (possibly) larger than the other. (if int = 32 bit and double = 64bit)

Comment: You won't necessary get a crash. Setting one and accessing the other is almost always undefined behaviour anyway.

Comment: If you are accessing memory outside the memory you've allocated then you get an out of range exception. since the structs only differ by one int vs a double if they are the same size the structs are the same size. if the int is smaller than the double accessing the double when you've allocated the int then you're accessing memory you don't own. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I wouldn't be accessing SalaryInfo if I was allocating HourlyInfo. Any employee is either a hourly or salary employee, not both. Note that I'll be creating an array of these unions. RE: "completely pointless" ... do you want to expand on that?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't throw exceptions when you go back on the compiler's trust not to go digging in memory that isn't yours, it's just undefined behaviour. Anyway, even if these *were* the same size (which they very well could be with padding), it would still be undefined behaviour to access the union member that was not last set in the first place.

Comment: Regarding completely pointless, well all you do is save yourself a reinterpret_cast. It's better going with one of the other suggested methods since they either tell you what type it is by a dynamic_cast (slow) or by a bool (only tells you it's the other by implication). Only having the pointers in the union means you don't know what kind it is, and you could have just put the struct in and gotten rid of the extra memory access.

Also, I though padding only worked on a 32 bit basis. Why would one struct pad by an extra 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue here.

Note that:

- You won't be able to use both pointers to store different values simultaneously.
- You aren't saving much by encapsulating two (struct) pointers in a union.

Comment: It is C++ - not C. Typedefing or writing `struct` before struct name is not needed.

Comment: FWIW, I will be creating an array of these unions. Any employee is either an hourly or salaried employee, so your first bullet has already been considered.

Comment: RE: your second bullet, so would you say @VeriTi 's solution is a better approach? Which saves more memory or is more effective?